# Windows batch for loop sub routines and local variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

At work we use Windows batch files to run jobs off a scheduling tool. It's an old tool and approach but it works. I have to make new jobs fit the existing technology.

For this particular job I need pick up a number of files from a folder and load them into a SQL server database table. For each one I load I then need to run a bit of SQL to update the recently populated table.

So I have a for loop that looks for files in the folder. If one exists I use SQL server's BCP to load the data into a table. I then use SQL server's SQLCMD to perform the update.

The policy is when using BCP or SQLCMD to write any issues out to files. Post call we then check these files to ensure that nothing went wrong.

When dealing with a single file this is fairly straightforward stuff. Using a FOR loop is proving to be impossible.

I envisaged calling a sub routine which would set a variable that code in the for loop could check and if appropriate exit gracefully.

The first thing we do in the batch file is set a global variable to 0. When the batch job returns control to the 'scheduler' if this is not equal to 0 the job shows as failed.

So paraphrasing the code it looks something like the following.

```
SET g_status=0
SET LOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR n = 1 to 12
   IF FILE(n) EXISTS (
      Execute BCP....
      Execute SQLCMD....
      CALL check_sql_status
      IF !l_error_status! NEQ 0 ENDLOCAL & SET g_status=!l_error_status!
      IF g_status NEQ 0 GOTO exit_gracefully
      )
NEXT
.
.
GOTO END
REM ========
:check_sql_status
REM======
IF something is wrong (
   SET l_error_status=123

GOTO EOF

REM ========
:exit_gracefully
REM======
ECHO g_status

:End
.
.
```

Don't get hung up on the 'code' above. It's only the bit where I am attempting pass the local variable back to the global variable that I am interested in. No matter what I try I cannot get the global variable to accept the value set in the sub routine.

I will try to find this question and post some of the actual code when I get back to work although BCP and SQLCMD use lots of parameters that may just confuse rather than help.

Comment: Maybe my knowledge is lacking, but I don't think that's valid syntax for a FOR loop, or for `IF FILE(n) EXISTS` for that matter. It's hard to tell what's going on if you don't post the *real* code.

Comment: Does `sqlcmd` exit non-zero if there's a problem?  If so, you could do `sqlcmd parameters here && (success code block) || (fail code block)` using [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  Or you could `sqlcmd args` then `if errorlevel 1 ( something went wrong )` or similar.  Also, the `for` loop you're looking for is `for /L %%I in (start,step,end)` and `if exist "file(%%I)"`.  In a cmd console, `for /?` and `if /?` for more info.

Comment: As has been stated before... it is difficult to pinpoint what is wrong with the code when you are posting psuedo code. One serious problem is that l_error_status is not initialized. It may be undefined depending on what happens in the subroutine... which is missing a closing paren.

Comment: The most likely cause is that the subroutine is being run in a child instance of cmd.exe, which has no way to set a variable in the parent instance.  But without seeing some real code we can't tell you why or how best to fix it.  (However, I would hazard a guess you're using brackets inappropriately.)

Comment: I vote to close this question. We can only guess what the problem might be until actual code is posted.